# FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator not present in latest spring-context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-context

I am using FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator which comes from org.springframework:spring-context. With the latest pom upgrade I see this class is not present in spring-context jar. What is the substitute of this class now? I am using org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.25.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

you have upgraded from which version to 4.3.25-RELEASE

If we follow the spring documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.html

this annotation was introduced since 5.2.3

can you please try using this 5.2.3 or above version and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. if your spring-context is lower than  5.2.3.RELEASE.

Use this approach:

1. You can implement your own bean-name generation strategy which use fully-qualified name:

```
public class UniqueBeanNameGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {
       
    @Override
    public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        return definition.getBeanClassName();
    }
}
```

2. Add this to spring boot app start class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator=UniqueNameGenerator.class)
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```